# Unable to locate ansible after installing on MacOS

Tags: macos, ansible

Installed ansible using pip on my macOS running Mojave (10.14.6)

```
pip install --user ansible
```

After running I got a successful installation

```
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyYAML-5.1.2 ansible-2.8.5 asn1crypto-1.0.1 cffi-1.12.3 cryptography-2.7 enum34-1.1.6 ipaddress-1.0.22 jinja2-2.10.3 pycparser-2.19
```

Running my first command

```
Macbook:~ t0o0tz$ ansible --version
-bash: ansible: command not found
```

Locate yielded no results. I ran an upgrade and received a bunch of:

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade
```

During the upgrade I also got a location for ansible

```
ansible in /Users/t0o0tz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.8.5)
```

But could not find ansible in 'site-packages'

site-packages contents below:

```
Extras.pth          easy-install.pth        vboxapi
README              pip-19.2.3-py2.7.egg        vboxapi-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi t0o0tz, welcome to SO. Did you not find a directory `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable file was located in $HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin

```
    ./ansible --version
ansible 2.8.5
```

Thanks Matthew L Daniel!